# How can I implement global messages with Socket.io-client?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, socket.io-client

I succesfully implemented a real-time chat in specific 'room' with Socket.io-client.

And now, I want to make every message from every room make an alert from everywhere in my page even though the user doesn't actually enter every room.

So, I wrote codes like this.

```
const socket = io(server-url);
```

This Socket is managed with useContext. (The socket is connected in the ContextProvider)

```
useEffect(() => {
  socket.connect();
});
```

And I made this socket gets global messages in the `layout.js` where the `<Header/>, <Footer/>, <Outlet/>` is placed. Sadly, it doesn't work.
I don't have an access to the server code, but I know that there's no problem in the server.

```
const { socket } = useChatData();

useEffect(() => {
  socket.emit(`connect`, { socket: socketID });
  if (chats)
    socket.on("newMsg", data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
}, [socket]);
```

This code doesn't make any error, so I couldn't catch what's the problem.
How can I solve this?
I'll also be very happy for some feedbacks or advices for the concept or method of global messages with socket.io-client that are not related with my codes.

Comment: Are you talking about [broadcasting](https://socket.io/docs/v3/broadcasting-events/)?

Comment: I think this is a slightly different concept. In broadcasting, if my understanding is correct, the server sends the same message to connected clients. But I want some function that sends some notification of new messages from every room in ''the user's namespace''. But now, only when the user joined a specific room, the alert for that room is activated.

Comment: Note that socket.io _has_ namespaces, and you can broadcast to just a single namespace.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me the issue, but I hope the following actions can help you:

1. **Modify Dependency Array**:

   - Update your `useEffect`'s dependency array to:

   ```js
   }, [socket, chats]);
   ```
2. **Clean Up Event Listeners**:

   - Ensure you remove the event listener when the component unmounts.

   ```js
   useEffect(() => {
     const handleNewMsg = (data) => {
       console.log(data);
     };
     if (chats) {
       socket.on('newMsg', handleNewMsg);
     }
     return () => {
       socket.off('newMsg', handleNewMsg);
     };
   }, [socket, chats]);
   ```
3. **Avoid Multiple Connections**:

   - Disconnect the socket when the component unmounts:

   ```js
   useEffect(() => {
     socket.connect();
     return () => {
       socket.disconnect();
     };
   }, []);
   ```
4. **Rename the Emit Event**:

   - Change your `connect` event name to something like "userConnect".
5. **Place Listener in Higher Component**:

   - Ensure your socket listener is in a component that doesn't unmount often (e.g., App component or Context Provider).
6. **Double-Check Server Events**:

   - Confirm the server emits the "newMsg" event to the right client or room.
7. **Singleton Socket Instance**:

   - In your context, ensure there's only one instance of the socket for the entire app.

Start by implementing these steps individually, testing in between to pinpoint and resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer!:) I'll revise my codes according to your advice!